# R shiny: conditionalPanel with condition based on textInput (how to)

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use a conditionPanel that would appear only if a preceding textInput has been completed (the initial value of it being ""). What is the right way to define the condition in the conditionalPanel correctly. Here is a reproducible code:

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("TEST"),
sidebarPanel(
textInput('test', "","")),

mainPanel(               
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.test != "" ", #problem is here. I've tried many possibilities (such as input.test > 0) but none have worked
                 helpText("abc"))
)
)

server <- function(input,output){ 
}

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Any advice/suggestion would be greatly appreciated !

Cheers

Comment: Change the condition to `"input.test != ''"` or `"input.test.length > 0"`

Comment: many thanks Jake !!! (I was not too far but it's still a great learning point)

Comment: I added it as an answer with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, changing the condition to `"input.test != ''"` or `'input.test != ""'` works as it deals with the issue of having quotes within quotes.

The other solution is to change the condition to `"input.test.length > 0"` which works because if you look at the source code for `conditionalPanel` (below) it's just creating a `div` where the `data-display-if` attribute is the condition. Considering its going straight to html it was a good guess that using js for the condition would work.

And I could have just read the docs... From `?conditionalPanel`:

```
condition: A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly to
          determine whether the panel should be displayed.

conditionalPanel
function (condition, ...) 
{
    div(`data-display-if` = condition, ...)
}
```